# RegisterStartupScript doesn't work when firing from UpdatePanel under IIS 6.0 on Framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net, iis-6, updatepanel, c#-2.0, registerstartupscript

I've looked everywhere but haven't found a solution. Hope you could help:

I'm maintaining a web site written in VB.NET and runs under Framework 2.0.

In one of my pages I have a drop down control inside an UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlDropDown" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" Width="400"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="--- Please Select ---" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="111"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="222"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="333"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Inside the handler of this control, I have a call to ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript:

```
Protected Sub ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "Test", "alert('Test'); ", True)
End Sub
```

Now here is my problem:
When I choose a value from the drop down, the "RegisterStartupScript" method WON'T WORK, but it happens only when the project runs under IIS 6 and Framework 2.0.
- If I change it to run under IIS 7, it works perfectly.
- If I change it to run under Framework 4.0, it works perfectly.
- If I remove the UpdatePanel part, it works.

But if I don't change anything, it doesn't do anything.

Any solution before I change my whole code to work with jquery and ajax? :)

Thanks,

Orit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround that I found in order to avoid the use of RegisterStartupScript. It's simple and works perfectly:

1. I added a hidden field inside the UpdatePanel named "hdnTest":

   ```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlDropDown" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTest" runat="server" />
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" Width="400"
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
           <asp:ListItem Text="--- Please Select ---" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="111"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="222"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="333"></asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
   </ContentTemplate>
   ```
2. On server side, I inserted a value to the hidden field inside the handler of the control:

   ```
   Protected Sub ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
       If x Then
           hdnTest.Value = "true"
       Else
           hdnTest.Value = "false"
       End If
       pnlDropDown.Update()
   End Sub
   ```
3. On client side, I added a pageLoad() function, that gets the value of the hidden field and acts according to it:

   ```
    function pageLoad(){            
       if ($("#hdnTest").val() == "true") 
           alert('true');             
       else
           alert('false');               
    }
   ```

Works just great.

Orit.